# Wrote a calculator in Kotlin but delete button deletes in wrong order

Tags: android, kotlin

```
deleteClick.setOnClickListener() {
            val text = resultTextView.text.toString()
            if (text.isNotEmpty()) {
                resultTextView.text = text.drop(1)
            }
        }
```

Made a calculator in kotlin but when i want to delete last entered digit with "DEL" button with the code shown above it deletes from left to right starting with the first digit entered which is wrong. any ideas how to reverse that or fix that?

Comment: resultTextView.text = text.dropLast(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
deleteClick.setOnClickListener() {
            val text = resultTextView.text.toString()
            if (text.isNotEmpty()) {
                resultTextView.text = text.dropLast(1)
            }
        }
```